# Why is the bundle for a Swift Package not found when using Bundle.module?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground, swift-package-manager

I'm building a Swift Package library that contains a text resource inside `/swift-spk/Sources/SPK/Resources/names.txt`. The resource is being copied into the target as:

```swift
.target(
    name: "SPK",
    dependencies: [],
    resources: [
        .copy("Resources/names.txt")
]),
```

... The `Bundle.module` accessor is generated and I use it in a private function within the Swift Package (the Bundle.module call is performed from within the Swift Package). I run the code within a Playground file and the runtime fails with an error message:

```swift
SPK/resource_bundle_accessor.swift:27: Fatal error: unable to find bundle named swift-spk_SPK
```

I'm following the guidelines I found on tutorials and similar questions from last year here so I'm curious if there have been any changes to the resource loading.

Thanks in advance for any support